# How to unregister the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter in Spring 4.1.4?

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb2

Is there a way to unregister the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter in Spring 4.1.4?

Thanks,

Tonté

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag in your configuration because this configuration tells spring to automatically use pre-configured message converters.  When this happens the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter will automatically be registered if the jaxb libraries are on the classpath. Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter will be registered by default because the jab libraries come with the JDK 6 and higher. In order to unregister the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter, you will have to manually configured MarshallingHttpMessageConverter after you've removed the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag in your configuration and then manually configure your RequestMappingHandlerAdapter like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="messageConvertersList"/>
</bean>
```

And make sure the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter is not in your list of converters.